# How to login and communicate with php and curl

Tags: php, json, curl, authentication

Hi i'm trying send a post request with php cURL and json, i have this code and this is my first challenge with cURL and json.

Is an authenticated server, but i think that I don´t link to the server.. the `$curlResult` variable is empty.

this is my code

```
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$url_send = "url";
$str_data = "{\"lookupKey\":\"Ejemplo\",\"subject\":\"Prueba HideBanner\",\"body\":\"Esto es una prueba\",\"issuerName\":\"Karla\",\"recipient\":{\"legalName\":\"Tania\",\"emailAddress\":\"test@outlook.com\"},\"options\":{\"certificationlevel\":\"Standard\"}}";

function sendPostData($url, $post)
{
    echo "Line 57: sendPostData is working<br>";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curlresult == "OK") {
        $result = "The curl action was succeeded! (OUTPUT of curl is: " . $curlresult . ")";
    } else {
        $result = "The curl action has FAILED! (OUTPUT of curl is: " . $curlresult . ")";
    }

    echo $result;
    return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok well, you have two big mistakes in your script.

### 1. Out of Scope Variables

You try to use variables that are out of the scope inside the function `sendPostData`.
Look at `$username` and `$password` - inside the function these two variables are not present because you declared it outsite the function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

### 2. Case Sensitive Variables

In PHP Variables are case sensitive so if you declare `$curlResult` and check with `if( $curlresult == "OK" )` php don't know the variable `$curlresult` because the variable name is not equal to your declared `$curlResult`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php